How does the Push weapon mastery (and/or Repelling Blast) interact with occupied spaces?
I'm wondering what happens if I use a pike to push a target into another creature, such as another enemy.
Free Rules 2024: Weapon Master Properties

Push
If you hit a creature with this weapon, you can push the creature up to 10 feet straight away from yourself if it is Large or smaller.

Seems clear enough, but from a logical perspective, it seems like this lets me push them into another person. At that point, using normal logic, I'd say this would further destabilize both people, and maybe they should both roll e.g. acrobatics checks to see if they stay standing. Another outcome would be that the pushed creature ends up in an adjacent square.
This could come up both in situations where I want to disrupt a third party (push an enemy into another enemy), and situations where I want to push an enemy, but there is someone "on the other side". In the latter scenario, am I simply unable to push the target, or do they all get pushed like dominos?
I checked the glossary but couldn't find anything.
I checked the 2014 rules and found this definition of the Crusher feat from TCoE has has a related ability, but more specifics:

Crusher
...
Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage, you can move it 5 feet to an unoccupied space, provided the target is no more than one size larger than you.

This is a specific feat, so the rules are surely separate, but it is both better and worse. Better because the push doesn't have to be "straight away from you" like in the 2024 weapon mastery, but worse because it has to be "to an unoccupied space".
Considering that the push weapon mastery has no mention of "unoccupied space", and they had already considered this in a recent book, it seems like maybe it was intentionally left out. If not, it seems like a serious oversight.
To me, it would be very appropriate for the weapon master to have this exact same limitation. Even if it isn't logical (if I can push someone 10ft, why wouldn't I be able to use that to affect a third party), it's sensible for the game, and an appropriate nerf. If I really can push people into each other and create complex effects multiple times per round, it makes push very very strong.
EDIT RE: REPELLING BLAST
After accepting an answer, I realized this same question also applies to the Warlock Invocation Repelling Blast:

Repelling Blast[...] When you hit a Large or smaller creature with that cantrip, you can push the creature up to 10 feet straight away from you.

Both abilities use the same text "you can push the creature up to 10 feet straight away from you" with slightly different phrasing of the "Large or smaller" condition.
Thus, any clarification or answer (such as the selected one below) would logically apply to both. Notably, this similarity makes it seem even less like an oversight. If discussions over the years about Repelling Blast had made them want to make this more specific (as it is in Crusher), surely they would have added it in the 2024 rules.

Since presumably this doesn't let you push people through walls, I see no reason why it would let you push them into an occupied space.

Yeah, I thought of that too. There’s just no rule that says where I can and can’t push people. My feel on the rules is the general->specific premise starts with reality as “general”, so every stated rule overrides reality, and every specific rule overrides the less specific ones. In this case reality says a pushed person is stopped by a wall, but will crash into another person, so in absence of a rule about occupied space, the fact that someone wouldn’t go through a wall doesn’t stop them from knocking down another creature.

FWIW I posted this issue and the accepted answer on Reddit and it's getting downvoted to oblivion, in case you want to read some dissenting opinions: https://www.reddit.com/r/onednd/comments/1fykffj/push_weapon_mastery_and_repelling_blast_can_prone/

When you push them into another creature's space, they suffer the consequences of ending a turn in another creature’s space*
As you observe the Push weapon property does not exclude you pushing them into another creature's space, so you can do that. How is that handled by the game then?
See p. 25, PHB under Moving Around Other Creatures:

You can't willingly end a move in a space occupied by another creature. If you somehow end a turn in a space with another creature, you have the Prone condition (see the rules glossary) unless you are Tiny or are of a larger size than the other creature.

So what usually will happen is that at the end of your turn, the creatures that occupy the same space then both end the turn in a space with another creature and have the prone condition. (Unless one of them is tiny, or larger size than the other, in which case that creature won't be prone).

* Unless they have a readied action or other reaction that allows them to leave the other creature's space before the end of the turn, and use it. In that case, nothing special happens, as they are not ending a turn in another creature's space.

Holy moly that’s way too strong! You’re right though, your answer seems to be bulletproof. What an incredible source of crowd control if the DM allows it.

@jerclarke this rule for prone when you're in the same space as another is new in 2024 (there is no such rule in 2014 PHB), so presumably handling the new Push weapon mastery is one of its purposes

At first I was unsure whether "if you end a turn" is meant to mean the end of any creatures turn or just your own, but if they had meant this to only be for the end of your own turn, they would surely have phrased it "if you end your turn".

It just seems so unfair to the topple mastery, which can only affect one opponent and requires a roll. Being able to push one enemy and “topple” two of them with no save is outrageous.

FYI: I realized this question and answer are identical WRT Repelling Blast in the 2024 rules, so I updated the question to reflect that. If anyone has a clarification to add that applies to RB and not Push, please chime in

Ok, I think the best argument /against/ this answer is the following: The rule starts with "You can't willingly end a move...", then later "If you somehow end a turn..." Semantically the fact that the second part is in its own sentence means the statement stands on it's own, but pragmatically, it might be the intention that it is in fact tied to the first sentence in the paragraph. I.e. that it only applies to ending your own turn and resolving your own movement. It's a bit of a stretch, but the people on Reddit are harping on this point, so it's worth mentioning.

@jerclarke Yes, that's a stretch. If you cannot end willingly, but still can end in another space, you end up there because you were moved there by some external force, not your own movement. This can include things in your turn like falling as a consequence of moving over a cliff, but in most cases, it will be from being forced there by being pushed in some way. As you say it would have been easy to say "your own" or even "your" turn here, but they didn't say that. They said "a turn", and that can be any turn, yours or another's. Its even narratively makes sense, albeit its very strong.

@jerclarke: I was going to say there's no rule that makes pushing one enemy "topple" two of them, but on rereading, yeah, the wording of ending "a turn", not "your turn", does imply that if you perform this push, as soon as your own turn ends, anyone that didn't have a reaction to achieve additional movement within your turn would end up prone. That is a pretty nice ability.

I am leaning that it would not work, because there are not rules that allow you to use forced movement to move a creature into another creature's space.
The rules for movement (using your speed, so not forced movement) explicitly say there are certain conditions that allow for you to move through another creatures space

Moving around Other Creatures
During your move, you can pass through the space of an ally, a
creature that has the Incapacitated condition (see the rules
glossary), a Tiny creature, or a creature that is two sizes larger or
smaller than you.
Another creature’s space is Difficult Terrain for you unless that
creature is Tiny or your ally.
You can’t willingly end a move in a space occupied by another
creature. If you somehow end a turn in a space with another creature,
you have the Prone condition (see the rules glossary) unless you are
Tiny or are of a larger size than the other creature.

Natural Language strikes again. In order for these rules to work at all we need to make some inferences.
We need to make the assumption that by default you cannot move into another creature's space. Because the language here is written permissively, only telling you ways you can do something, if we do not make this assumption, then these rules restrict nothing. This would make these rules redundant and is clearly not the intent.
Following that assumption, we see there is a set of criteria you can meet to be an exceptions to this implied rule:

You must be using your move.
The creature must be your ally, have the incapacitated condition, be
a tiny creature, or be a creature that is two sizes larger than you.

Any forced movement fails to fulfill the first of these two conditions.
For this interaction to work as you describe, a similar exception would need to be made for forced movement.
In this reading, the condition:

If you somehow end a turn in a space with another creature, you have
the Prone condition (see the rules glossary) unless you are Tiny or
are of a larger size than the other creature

refers to any scenario that would force you to lose movement speed after you have already moved into the space of another creature and have no remaining movement. That is also why this is in the rules for "Moving around Other Creatures" and not in a more general section about positioning.
I really don't like this whole bit as this creates additional complications. For example, the old Falling rules had clarification on what happened if a creature fell on another which is altogether lacking here too. A reasonable person might assume this would cause a creature to enter the same space, but there is nothing in the rules that would indicate that.

Hey George! Thanks for joining the SE and assembling this answer! I’m glad to have the dissenting opinion documented here! Hopefully some day we get a clarification and can update this!
